# VHDL traffic lights FSM using LPM counter: where to set/reset counter?

Tags: vhdl, fsm

This one has been boggling my mind for the last two days so i've came to the internets for help.

Bit of background info first...
I'm working on a traffic lights project for uni using an Altera DE0 board. I'm a complete n00b with regards to VHDL and this first assignment was more or less a case of "here's an example of a finite state machine and an example of an LPM counter, go make some traffic lights". I think the idea's just to get a feel for using VHDL and mess about with the code to get something working.

We were given an example from a textbook (Free Range VHDL p93 iirc) on an FSM then shown how to make an LPM counter using the Megawizard Plugin Manager in Quartus and basically just had to merge/expand them. Its the first thing i've done using VHDL.

The traffic lights are supposed to be for an intersection of a major road and minor road. The default state will be major road green and minor road red. It should stay in this state until it detects a pushbutton (i.e. a car at the minor road) then go amber then red, then the minor road will go from red to green and stay in green for 10 seconds. It will stay in each other state for 1 second.
I've used 9 states (A-I) and one LPM counter and i'm just looking for a 1 in bit 26 and 29 of the "q" output(?) of the counter for the 1 and 10 second delay.

My problem is that i'm not sure where to set and reset the timer. Technically it should be reset after moving into each state then set (i.e. allowed to count) when moving to the next state.

I'll paste my code below, currently the timer_rst bits are commented out. I've tried placing them in all different lines in the code but the closest i've came to having it work is setting and resetting the timer where those commented out set and reset parts are. When i un-comment them out one at a time and run it each time it'll go from state A to B then C but after that it'll just skip to E then it moves through states so quick all the LEDs light and it seems to jump randomly through different states. Obviously this isn't how it should be done!

Can anyone help me out then?

I hope i've given a decent enough explanation here. I'll paste a link to a video of the board running my code and you can check the code out below too.

Thanks for any help provided!

```
--Finite state machine using DE0 board implementing a set
--of traffic tights at a major road/minor road junction.
--Major road is green until car present at minor road 
--then goes to red while minor road goes to green.
--8 states, A-H. A is 'default' state
--1 sec delay: state B,C,D,F,G,H, 10 sec delay: state E,I.
--Maj Rd lights: LEDG(5 downto 3) Red/Amber/Green.
--Min Rd lights: LEDG(2 downto 0) Red/Amber/Green.
--State vector printed on LEDG(9 downto 6) in binary                             

--library declarations
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

LIBRARY lpm;        --allows use of Altera LPM functions  
USE lpm.all;

--entity
entity TRAFFICLIGHTS is
  port( 
    KEY      : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0); --minor rd car present KEY(1) & reset KEY(0)-ACTIVE LOW!
    CLOCK_50 : in std_logic;
    LEDG       : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); --6 lights 2 * (red/amber/green) & state vector
    HEX0        : out std_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)      --display current state
  ); 
end TRAFFICLIGHTS;

-- architecture
architecture TRAFFICLIGHTS_arch of TRAFFICLIGHTS is
type state_type is (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I);
signal PS, NS       : state_type;
signal timer_rst    : std_logic;    --wiring to delay components , one_sec, ten_sec
signal timer_q  : std_logic_vector(29 downto 0);        --output from timer 
--LPM counter  
component timer
    PORT
    (
        aclr        : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        clock       : IN STD_LOGIC ;
        q           : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (29 DOWNTO 0)    --uses bit 29 for 10 secs, bit 26 for 1 sec
    );
end component;

begin

--wiring up LPM counter to signals
U1 : timer
    PORT MAP (
        aclr  => timer_rst,
        clock => clock_50,
        q     => timer_q
);

--detects change in clock, next state or reset key press
sync_proc: process (clock_50, NS, KEY(0))
    begin
        if (KEY(0)='0') then    --if reset pressed, return to state A
            PS <= A;
            elsif (rising_edge(clock_50)) then      --else put present state in next state
            PS <= NS;
        end if;
    end process sync_proc;

--detect change in present state or KEY(1) i.e. minor road car present  
comb_proc: process (PS, KEY(1))

begin

    case PS is
            when A => --when in A: MajRd green, MinRd red, no delay
                --show state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0001";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10001000";   --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '1'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

                if (KEY(1) = '0') then 
                    --timer_rst <= '1'; -- reset timer
                    --timer_rst      <= '0';    -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <=  B; --if car present @MinRd, next state is B
                else    NS <= A;
                end if;

            when B => --when in B: MajRd amber, MinRd red, 1 sec delay
                --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0010";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10000011";     --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '1'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen    

                if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
                --timer_rst <= '1'; -- reset timer
                  --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                        NS        <= C;
                else  NS         <= B;
                end if;

            when C => --when in C: MajRd red, MinRd red, 1 sec delay
                --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0011";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "11000110";         --display state on 7 seg

                LEDG(5) <= '1'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen    

                if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
                  --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
                  --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= D;
                else  NS             <= C;
                end if;

            when D => --when in D: MajRd red, MinRd red/amber, 1 sec delay
                --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0100";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10100001";         --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '1'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '1'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

                if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
                  --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
                        --timer_rst <= '0'; -- allow timer to count
                  NS        <= E;
                else  NS             <= D;
                end if;

            when E => --when in E: MajRd red, MinRd green, 10 sec delay
                --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0101";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10000110";         --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '1'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '0'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '1'; --MinGreen    

            if (timer_q(29) = '1') then
              --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
              --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= F;
            else  NS             <= E;
            end if;

        when F => --when in F: MajRd red, MinRd amber, 1 sec delay
            --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
            LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0110";
            HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10001110";         --display state on 7 seg
            LEDG(5) <= '1'; --MajRed
            LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
            LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
            LEDG(2) <= '0'; --MinRed
            LEDG(1) <= '1'; --MinAmber
            LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

            if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
              --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
              --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= G;
            else  NS             <= F;
            end if;         

        when G => --when in G: MajRd red, MinRd red, 1 sec delay
            --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
            LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0111";
            HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10010000";         --display state on 7 seg
            LEDG(5) <= '1'; --MajRed
            LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
            LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
            LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
            LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
            LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

            if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
              --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
              --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= H;
            else  NS             <= G;
            end if;

        when H => --when in H: MajRd red/amber, MinRd red, 1 sec delay
            --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
            LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "1000";
            HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10001001";         --display state on 7 seg
            LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
            LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
            LEDG(3) <= '1'; --MajGreen
            LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
            LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
            LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

            if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
              --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
              --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= I;
            else  NS             <= H;
            end if;

        --new state allows MajRd to stay green (10 sec) if car at MinRd or not
        when I => --when in I: MajRd green, MinRd red, 10 sec delay
            --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
            LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "1001";
            HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "11111001";         --display state on 7 seg
            LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
            LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
            LEDG(3) <= '1'; --MajGreen
            LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
            LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
            LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

            if (timer_q(29) = '1') then 
              --timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
              --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <= C;
            else  NS             <= A;
            end if;

        when others => -- the catch-all condition
          PS <= A; -- if anything else, return to state A
    end case;
  end process comb_proc;
end TRAFFICLIGHTS_arch;
```

Video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/70tkr67zdjj8pyk/File%2018-03-2015%2017%2057%2054.mov?dl=0

Tried adding intermediate states, here's the code from the case statement for the first few below. Its just starting and jumping straight to state B now and not going anywhere.

```
    case PS is
            when A => --when in A: MajRd green, MinRd red, no delay
                --show state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0001";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10001000";   --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '0'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '1'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

                if (KEY(1) = '0') then 
                    timer_rst <= '1';   -- reset timer
                    --timer_rst      <= '0';    -- allow timer to count
                    NS        <=  B; --if car present @MinRd, next state is B
                else    NS <= A_1;
                end if;

            when A_1 =>
                --LEDs and 7 seg same as A
                LEDG(9 downto 0) <= "0001001100";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10001000";   --display state on 7 seg
                timer_rst    <= '0';    -- allow timer to count
                NS <= B;

            when B => --when in B: MajRd amber, MinRd red, 1 sec delay
                --print state vector using 4 bit binary 1-8
                LEDG(9 downto 6) <= "0010";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10000011";     --display state on 7 seg
                LEDG(5) <= '0'; --MajRed
                LEDG(4) <= '1'; --MajAmber
                LEDG(3) <= '0'; --MajGreen
                LEDG(2) <= '1'; --MinRed
                LEDG(1) <= '0'; --MinAmber
                LEDG(0) <= '0'; --MinGreen

                if (timer_q(26) = '1') then 
                      timer_rst <= '1'; -- reset timer
                  --timer_rst <= '0';   -- allow timer to count
                        NS        <= B_1;
                else  NS         <= B;
                end if;

            when B_1 =>
                --LEDs and 7 seg same as B
                LEDG(9 downto 0) <= "0010010100";
                HEX0(7 downto 0) <= "10000011";     --display state on 7 seg
                timer_rst    <= '0';    -- allow timer to count
                NS <= C;
```

Comment: One easy way would be to add intermediate states to reset your counter. A -> A_1 -> B, where A_1 is active a single clock and reset happens. For your own sake, use meaningful state name like Mj_Red_Mi_Green or anything you fancy, it will be way easier to follow!

Comment: Intermediate states you say? That's definitely an idea! I'll give that a go. Cheers.

Comment: So I've tried implementing your suggestion but its now just loading up straight into state B and staying there. I'll paste what i've changed:

Comment: First, in a combinational process any signal you assign must be assigned in all path (every case, every if/else). For instance, timer_rst is not assigned in that else of state A. If you look at your state B, timer_rst is never released since it depends on timer_q. In your A,B,C... state, have timer_rst always '0'. In state A_1,B_1,... have timer_rst always '1'. Like that, you will have a moore machine, where outputs are only determined from states and not inputs.

Comment: OK Jonathan, i'll give that a go. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Chris, check "FINITE STATE MACHINES IN HARDWARE...", V. A. Pedroni, MIT Press, page 166.